# Why is my xml data taken from a jsp page not showing in jqgrid?

Tags: jsp, jqgrid

I'm trying to load data (in xml form) into my jqgrid from a jsp page, but I can't understand why I'm not seeing the data inside the grid. I tried everything, but it's still not working.

This is my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function()
{                
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
            url:'server.jsp',
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: 'GET' ,
            colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
            colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:75},
                    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
                    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
                    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},
                    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},
                    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            autowidth: true,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
            sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"XML Example"
    }).navGrid('#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false}); 

});
```

```
                <table id="list1"></table>
                <div id="pager1"></div>
```

This is my jsp page:

```
<%

    response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=utf-8");
%>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>

<rows>
<page>1</page>
<total>5</total>
<records>5</records>
<row id='1'>
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>2</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
<cell>3</cell>
<cell>4</cell>
<cell>5</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
</row>
<row id='2'>
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>2</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
<cell>3</cell>
<cell>4</cell>
<cell>5</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
</row>
<row id='3'>
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>2</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
<cell>3</cell>
<cell>4</cell>
<cell>5</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
</row>
<row id='4'>
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>2</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
<cell>3</cell>
<cell>4</cell>
<cell>5</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
</row>
<row id='5'>
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>2</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
<cell>3</cell>
<cell>4</cell>
<cell>5</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[eeeeeee]]></cell>
</row>
</rows>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably search for the reason of the problem somewhere else.

How you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LoadFromXML.htm) the code which you posted do display the data. One remark only the value of `total` should be the number of pages and not the number of records, but the XML data looks more as a dummy data.

Comment: the problem was solved, Ive changed my grid to datatype: 'xmlstring'- so now it's works. but i didn;t not find a solution for the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue using JSON data, jquery 1.5, and jquery.validate.min.js.

Version 1.8 of jquery.validate.min.js resolves this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Add **autoencode: true,** in your JQgrid

```
  jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
            url:'server.jsp',
            datatype: "xml",
            autoencode: true,
            mtype: 'GET' ,
```